# Is it safe to use a Spring BeanPostProcessor with reflection to change private field values in the bean

Tags: java, spring, reflection

I am using Springs BeanPostProcessor to loop through all the declared fields for the passed in bean, and if any of them has a particular annotation, then I want to modify that fields value in some way.

The code to do this (omitting the annotation declaration) looks roughly like the below, and seems work correctly (so far):

```
@Component
public class AnnotationProcessingBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    
    @Override
    public final Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public final Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, final String beanName) {
        Field[] fields = bean.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        List<Field> fieldsWithAnno = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(SomeAnno.class)) {
                try {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    field.set(bean, "HELLO WORLD!");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return bean;
    }
}
```

My concern is, I believe the beans themselves are wrapped in some sort of proxy object, so the actual instance of the bean here is not a DIRECT instance of my particular bean.

So could doing this sort of thing cause some unforseen issue?

**What I am ACTUALLY trying to achieve**

I want to annotate fields with something like:

```
@GetStringFromFile(fileName = "whatever.txt")
private String somePrivField;
```

Then when I find a field with that annotation, I will read the file in, and inject it's String value, and if the file doesn't exist or can't be read properly, throw an exception, and stop my spring app from starting up.

Comment: Well safe, probably. Maybe use the Spring `ReflectionUtils` to make the code a little easier. However why not use a `Resource` instead of a `String` and when needed read it and return the value. Saves you from this contraption and magic.

Comment: Thanks will take a look at `ReflectionUtils`. I don't use a `Resource`, because then every class that uses this needs extra code to read the resource, this way it's just the annotation and field name and done. But true, this is perhaps overengineering things I guess.

Comment: It is just 1 or 2 lines of code to read it and you probably can put that into a utility method/class.